# How to invoke sh shell with file using Runtime.getRuntime().exec?

Tags: java, runtime.exec, processbuilder

How to invoke sh file in linux terminal using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` in java ?

I want to invoke the sh file in new terminal from java code. If i run it in terminal only it runs as a separate process, which will not be closed even if my programs exits. And thats why I'm not using `ProcessBuilder`, which stops the process invoked by it if the program using it exits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Runtime.getRunTime().exec not behaving like C language "system()" command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665185/runtime-getruntime-exec-not-behaving-like-c-language-system-command)

Comment: What you have to do is run a terminal emulator, passing the script as a parameter. Which terminal emulator do you use? Xterm, gnome-terminal, konsole, ... ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I launch a completely independent process from a Java program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931536/how-do-i-launch-a-completely-independent-process-from-a-java-program)

Answer (score 0):

If your script is marked as executable (`chmod +x script.sh`), you can invoke it by `exec("./script.sh")`. Otherwise you can directly call it using `exec("sh script.sh")`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", "sh myfile.sh" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `ProcessBuilder` is just a thin wrapper around `Runtime`, using it directly will not do what you want.

Instead, you need to write a second script which creates a terminal window as a background process and detaches this process. General approach:

1. `ProcessBuilder` to start outer script
2. Outer script uses the Linux command [nohup(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) to create a detached process for inner script. For example: `nohup xterm -e /bin/bash "script.sh &"

`nohup` cuts the connections between the new X terminal and the Java process. `&` sends the whole thing into the background, so the command doesn't until `xterm` exits.