# Process not being spawned?

Tags: java

I am attempting to spawn a new process with the following code:

```
String exec = (System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/privateers.jar");
        String[] command = {"javaw", "-jar", exec};  
        final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        System.out.println("Running " + exec);
        System.exit(0);
```

But for some reason, the process just is not running.

The `"Running: " + exec` prints out `Running D:\Downloads\mcp\ship\ShipLauncher/privateers.jar`

When I go to `D:\Downloads\mcp\ship\ShipLauncher/`, there is a valid file names "privateers.jar" and which works absolutely fine when I open it with a bat file:

```
java -jar privateers.jar
PAUSE
```

There are absolutely no errors in the console.
[image]

Does anyone know the issue here? I cannot seem to find the problem.

**Update:**
I tried using `ProcessBuilder`. but no luck.

```
String exec = (System.getProperty("user.dir") + java.io.File.separator + "privateers.jar");
        String[] command = {"java", "-jar", exec}; 
        ProcessBuilder pb =
                   new ProcessBuilder(command[0], command[1], command[2]);
        progressBar.setValue(100); 
        System.out.println(pb.command());
        pb.start();
        //final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        System.out.println("Running " + exec);
```

Comment: Use `ProcessBuilder` instead

Comment: As you are using Windows, did you try do put a `\ ` instead of a `/` ? (`String exec = (System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\privateers.jar");`)

Comment: It may be exiting because its parent process is exiting.  Try replacing `System.exit(0);` with `Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);`.

Comment: unfortunately, you can't do it lke this.  any forked processes will be killed when the parent process exits.  you need an intermediate script to make this truly work.

Comment: Start testing by reading the stdout from the process and using `waitFor` on the process and check the return (exit) value

Comment: see my answer here (for linux, you can do a similar thing with windows batch files using the "start" command) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665185/runtime-getruntime-exec-not-behaving-like-c-language-system-command

Comment: @SergeBallesta Better would be `System.getProperty("user.dir") + java.io.File.separator + "privateers.jar"`.

Comment: Still looking for an answer. All comments so far have been useless.

Comment: @MadProgrammer return value was 0. Nothing odd there.

Comment: @jtahlborn I am fine with not killing the parent process, I guess. EDIT: not killing the parent process does nothing to fix the issue.

Comment: @JigarJoshi Tried that, no change.

Comment: @jtahlborn What? How does this relate at all to my problem?

Comment: @jtahlborn: Not true. On Unix, when a parent process dies, child processes get reparented to the `init` process. On Windows, no such thing as `fork` to begin with.

Comment: Can you try running the .bat file from within java instead and seeing what happens?

Comment: @Thomas - i know how unix works, however, that is not how _java_ works.  Java does not allow children to live longer than the parent.  I know this because we need to do this for our product on both windows and linux, and the only way to get it to work is to use an intermediate script.  (and i was using the word "fork" in the generic OS sense, not the posix function sense).

Comment: I would suggest actually checking the standard output and error streams of the launched process as well as the exit code.  _one_ of these should give some indication of the problem.